# React material-ui : Selection box over ListItemButton do not fit the cornerRadius

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a selectable menu items icons in React using Material UI with cornerRadius :

```
<Paper sx={{borderRadius: '25px'}}>
    <List component={Stack} direction="row">
        <ListItemButton>
            <CropSquareRounded />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton>
            <CropSquareRounded />
        </ListItemButton>
        <ListItemButton>
            <CropSquareRounded />
        </ListItemButton>
    </List>
</Paper>
```

When the mouse is over a item in this menu, the selection box do not fit the corner radius. The selection box is still rectangular.

[see square corner on selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixqUb.jpg)

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to style the `hover` state of your `ListItemButton` to achieve what you want:

```
<ListItemButton
              sx={{
                "&:hover": {
                  borderRadius: "16px"
                }
              }}
            >
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/listitem-border-radius-sov3g?file=/demo.tsx:656-808)